# Convert date into dd.mm.yyy

Tags: mysql

I found several questions about converting the format of date or datetime but it doesn't work.
I used type datetime for 'rdate' and tried to do

SQL Convert Datetime to Date

It should be the easiest and fastest way to convert a DATETIME to a DATE and I used

*SELECT CONVERT(date, rdate) FROM sreservations*;

Unfortunately it isn't working.

I tried the same with the type date but I couldn't find a solution either.

[Picture of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb3bs.png)

Comment: What about just DATE(rdate)?

Comment: That's not working.

Comment: your question isn't very clear.  if you wanted to make it clear, edit it to show output of `show create table sreservations;` (as text, not an image), some insert statements for sample data, and the results you want for that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

From your image, you don't seem to have a datetime, just a date.  You can format it (or a datetime, if you did have a datetime) into a string for display in mysql using date_format:

```
select date_format(rdate, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

if you want it to appear as dd.mm.yyyy.

Comment: Because I changed it back to date. :)

Comment: if all you wanted was to take a datetime field and select just the date part of it, as a date type, `date(rdate)` would do that, as Broken Arrow suggested above.

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot

I do have a bigger statement

    SELECT * FROM sreservation WHERE user_fk = $user UNION 
    SELECT * FROM preservation WHERE user_fk = $user UNION
    SELECT * FROM greservation WHERE user_fk = $user ORDER BY rdate";

What would be the correct use of select date_format(rdate, '%d.%m.%Y') in the statement?

Comment: Instead of *, list all the columns in your table(s) explicitly, but replace rdate with the date_format call.  Or just add it as a separate result column `select *, date_format(rdate, '%d.%m.%Y') as formatted_rdate`.  But doing `select *` is bad practice anyway

Comment: I used your advice and I changed it and it is working.

now i can't use ORDER BY rdate anymore because I formatted the rdate into formatted_rdate


SELECT reserv_id, user_fk, seat_id, date_format(rdate, '%d.%m.%Y') as formatted_rdate, time_zone, date_format(reg_date, '%d.%m.%Y  %h:%m:%s') as formatted_reg_date FROM greservation ORDER BY formatted_rdate";

If I order by rdate an empty list will occur. I guess it is because rdate is now ordering it by day and not my year anymore. Do you have a solution for this as well?

Comment: order by will never cause an empty list; you are doing something else wrong.  ask a new question showing your table structure (from `show create table yourtablename`), your query,  insert statements for sample data, and your actual and desired results for that sample data (all as text, not images)

Comment: I have already found my mistake :)
Thank you a lot for helping me. It really got me further with my project.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your table columns which involve the column with date data type,

Use

```
   SET DATEFORMAT DMY
```

This is for Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: I didn't get you. I use phpmyadmin for my project